# power bi: different calculations for several rows

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Would you, please, help me to apply different calculations for 2 rows in power BI:

that is, to transform this table:

```
client_ids products purchased month
1          0        0         jan
2          1A       1         jan
2          1B       1         jan
3          0        0         jan
4          0        0         jan
5          0        0         feb
```

into this:

```
purchased jan feb
1         1   
0         3   1
```

That is, to perform calculations:

-on purchased = 0 - count over month, client

-on purchased = 1 - count distinct over month, client

Thank you.

I used the method:

-create the reference to the main query in the query editor

-drop the column with products

-drop duplicates

But this makes downloading the report slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the expected output, you can use two steps to obtain the result from the data:

Assuming this is your table with date:

[image]

**First**, calculate the month different compared with today to find recently month (you can try other method depend on your data nature):

```
Mon Diff = (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(Sheet1[date])) + (MONTH(NOW()) - MONTH(Sheet1[date]))
```

**Second**, rank the recent month as current:

```
rank = 
var ranking = RANKX(Sheet1,Sheet1[Mon Diff],,,Dense)
return
SWITCH(ranking,1,"prior",2,"current")
```

**Third**, generate distinct values from purchase column

```
Table = DISTINCT(Sheet1[purchased])
```

**Fourth**, calculate the frequencies of 0 & 1 in Prior Month, the same for Feb

```
  Jan = CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[rank]),Sheet1[rank]="prior",
        Sheet1[purchased]=EARLIER('Table'[purchased])) 


 Feb = CALCULATE(COUNT(Sheet1[rank]),Sheet1[rank]="current",
        Sheet1[purchased]=EARLIER('Table'[purchased]))
```

The New table for the infor (In Jan, purchase [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOEah.png) has 2 occurrence instead of 1):

[image]

Comment: Kin Siang, thank you. The first step (creation the column with distinct values) gave me the error: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected. I also would be happy to automate the process of calculation the statistics for each month, since every month I have to include the last month to report and exclude the first.

Comment: `Distinct` function should only return unique value, why are you getting the error, or the table your display is not from data source but matrix table?  Your second part can be solved by convert month to index of 1 and 2, then it will be automatic calculate, you get my point?

Comment: Kin Siang, thank you for reply. I not at all got your point. Yes, I have a matrix table. Should I create a sepparate table using DISTINCT, like a dictionary. Concerning convertation month to integers, I have information for different years, therefore it is not sufficient to convert months only to numbers. Will be happy if you give me more details.

Comment: Definitely it will return error when you attempt to obtain `distinct` value from matrix table, you should obtain the value from source table only. See my edited answer about calculate for fix value.